# override inline style background-image

Tags: css, inline-styles

I need to override the following inline style:

```
<div class="header" style="background:url(http://domain.org/headers/header_image.jpg) top right repeat-y;">
```

I have tried the adding the below in an external style sheet but it is not working.

```
.header[style] {background-image:none;!important}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: it's just .header not .header[style] and !important goes on the inside, before the ;

Comment: Try not to use !important if you can avoid it. Plus your !important should be within your semi-colon. The key is specifity. Try also specifying the parent of .header in your rule.

Comment: @EliGassert `.header[style]` targets all `.header` classes with the style attribute set, hence over riding the inline style (and not causing any damage anywhere else)

Comment: Billy nothing will be more specific than inline styles, unfortunately.

Comment: @EliGassert - An inline-style does get more weight but it's not specific (well, not in the way I mean it). By talking about specificity I'm talking about writing a rule like "body .wrap .header a img". I.E. being very specific about the element you're trying to get to by using the DOm tree structure to the maximum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have almost got it, just do the following changes and it should work

```
.header[style] {background-image:none !important;}
```

The `!important` rule should be within your rule declaration only!

For a reference.. [click here](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/)

Comment: @pjp: He can't do that immediately. Be patient. With a 60% rate I'm sure he knows how to accept answers.

Comment: sorry for the delay, wouldnt let me for accept for a while then I forgot.  PS.  Im a she ;0)

Comment: ohh ok! :p no problem.happens! ;)